# cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported. with long list of bind variables

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm trying to get cx_oracle to execute an insert statement on a table where I'm passing about 134 variables into the table. i tested it on 2 bound variables and everything works fine but when i increase it to my required count i keep getting the error that tuples aren't supported.

`cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported.`

my execute statement is:

```
sql="INSERT into table (col1, col2, col3, col4...) VALUES (:c1,:c2,:c4,:c4...)"
cursor.execute(sql,c1=1,c2=2,c3=3,c4=4...)
```

I've tried it as a dict:

```
sql="INSERT into table (col1, col2, col3, col4...) VALUES (:c1,:c2,:c4,:c4...)"
row_data=dict(c1=1,c2=2,c3=3,c4=4...)
cursor.execute(sql,row_data)
```

I've also tried passing `row_data` as a `tuple` and a `list`:

```
sql="INSERT into table (col1, col2, col3, col4...) VALUES (:c1,:c2,:c4,:c4...)"
row_data=(1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
cursor.execute(sql,row_data)
```

At this point I'm thinking i need to loop through all the columns but i feel like there has to be a better way to pass a long list of vars to this execute that I'm missing

Comment: Print the value of row_data. One of the items in *that* tuple is a tuple -- which is not supported.

Comment: sob. you're right. running this in lmabda and for whatever reason its returning all the vars as tuples. wasnt doing that locally.